# proper way to get entity indicator id from end of route in react?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote some code to get an entity indicator id from the end of a route in a React component:

```
const pathname = this.props.location.pathname;
const lastPathPart = pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
const requestedJobId = Number(lastPathPart);
```

The code above gets the requested job id from the end of the route as needed/expected but is there a more proper or structured way to do this in React?

Comment: what path are you passing to the `Route`  ? How does this `pathname` look like .

Comment: Are you using component classes or hooks?

Comment: my app uses classes (not hooks).  the route looks like this:
http://localhost:5001/MyApp/Home/Messages/4000000408

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If it's a functional component, You can use `react-router`'s `useParams` hook.

**Example:**

Let's assume this is your route.

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/:id" children={<User />} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now you can use the `useParams` hook to extract the `id` inside the `User` component like this.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router";

function User() {
  let { id } = useParams();
  return <h2>User {id}</h2>;
}
```

**2.** If it's a class component you can refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316195/14143312).