# Get url params in ReactJS when using class component

Tags: reactjs

This is my URL in react js

http://localhost:3000/meassger/student/1

I want to extract `1` from the URL if it was a functional component I could have used ```useParams``

I am getting this error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')`

```
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params.id, "");
   
    };
```

Comment: Look at window.location object. Check path if includes student try some conditions

Comment: What router do you use? For react-router the way to access the params would be something like this `props.match.params['paramName'] `

Comment: @TeraWattHour can u write a answer based on my question it would be helpful for me and others

Comment: @meon did my solution work for you?

Comment: what version of `react-router` you are currently using?

Answer (score 4):

In functional component, use

```
const history = useHistory()

const studentId = history?.location?.pathname.split('/')[3]
```

In class component, use

```
const studentId = window.location.href.split('/')[3]
```

Comment: There are specific methods in React for doing this kind of operation, e.g. `withRouter`. You should avoid doing direct manipulation of the window or document (where possible) because the React VDOM does not keep a track of that.

Comment: @crevulus The useHistory hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: But this question is about class components and your method for class components is risky. Plus, you linked to react router v5 - in v5 `useHistory` is deprecated in favour of `useNavigation`.

Comment: @crevulus Please look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078332/is-it-secure-to-use-window-location-href-directly-without-validation#:~:text=The%20first%20one%2C%20using%20the,of%20user%20input%20as%20well.

Comment: that answer is almost 8 years old... React didn't even exist then. In plain JS this method is fine - and it's not the worst thing in the world to do in React. But there is a React way to do things because React has the vdom which it needs to keep track of any and all changes/properties within the application. And using the correct methods, hooks etc. are safer when working in React because of this vdom. By directly interacting with `window.location.href`, you're circumventing the vdom. This should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap it in withRouter - that injects the URL variables into your props.

You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316195/13063136

The code:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class ShowTheID extends React.Component {

  const { match } = this.props;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(match.params.id)
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{match.params.id}</div>;
  }
}

const ShowTheIDWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheID);
```

> ***Note: Along with wrapping your component in `withRouter` you also need to make sure that your route is registered and you have mentioned URL params in your Route path like path="/meassger/student/:id"***

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume we have a url like http://localhost:3000/student/:studentId and we need to grab studentId param from this url

In a functional component, we can do it like

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Student = () => {
    const { studentId } = useParams();
    return (
        <div>StudentId: { studentId }</div>
    );
}
export default Student;
```

In a class based component, we can do it like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Student extends Component {
    render() {
        const { studentId } = this.props.match.params;
        return (
            <div>StudentId: { studentId }</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Student;
```

**Alternatively**, you can use withRouter HOC. By doing so, you can also access location and history props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Student extends Component {
  render() {
    const { location, history } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>StudentId: { match.studentId }</div>
        <div>Path: {location.pathname}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const StudentWithRouter = withRouter(Student);
```